# How can I update list values inside a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
perfect_data = {
    "1":   [1, 1, 0,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1 ], }
```

I need to replace `0` with `-1` in this dict.
It's what I tried:

```
for key in perfect_data.keys():
    perfect_data[key]*=2-1
    print(perfect_data[key])
```

But nothing changes when I print each item.

Comment: `x *= 2-1` is the same as `x *= 1`.

Comment: okey, how can I multiply each item of a list by two and then subtract 1 from it?

Comment: and multiplying a list doesn't yield the result you'd expect anyway <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line `perfect_data[key]*=2-1` with `perfect_data[key] = [x*2 -1 for x in perfect_data[key]]`

```
for key in perfect_data.keys():
    perfect_data[key] = [x*2 -1 for x in perfect_data[key]]
    print(perfect_data[key])
```

Output:

```
{'1': [1,  1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
-1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  -1,  -1,  1,  1,  1]}
```

Comment: As soon as newer Python versions will iterate over dict keys by default, you can ommit '.keys()' and go like that:


for key in perfect_data:
    perfect_data[key] =

Answer (score 1):

If I get the point, try this way:

```
for value in perfect_data.values():
  for i, e in enumerate(value):
    if e == 0: 
      value[i] = -1
print(perfect_data)
```

Comment: if you only want the dict's values, use `dict.values()` ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, why not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's what I tried and worked:

```
for key,value in perfect_data.items():
    perfect_data[key]=[2*x-1 for x in value]
    print(perfect_data[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea, what are you trying to achieve, but if strictly following your question, the answer is:

```
perfect_data = {
    "1":   [1, 1, 0,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1 ], 
}

for k,v in perfect_data.items():
    perfect_data[k] = [x or -1 for x in v]

print(perfect_data)
```

**Output**

```
{'1': [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Statement `x or -1` uses the fact that `0` gives `False` and `or-operator` returns first `non-false` argument.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
perfect_data['1'] = [i if i else -1 for i in perfect_data['1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
DATA = {"records": [{"key1": "AAA", "key2": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", "key4": "AAA"}]}



for name, datalist in DATA.iteritems():  # Or items() in Python 3.x


    for datadict in datalist:

        for key, value in datadict.items():

            if value == "AAA":

                datadict[key] = "XXX"


print (DATA)
```